# How to use DbMessageSource in yii2

Tags: internationalization, yii2, multilingual

i am using yii2 advanced template.and i dont understand how to use DbMessageSource.i read the guide and i created two tables source_message and message and i wrote in my common/config/main.php file this code 
                       `'*'=> [
                                'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
                                'sourceMessageTable'=>'{{%source_message}}',
                                'messageTable'=>'{{%message}}',
                                'enableCaching' => true,
                                'cachingDuration' => 3600
                            ],` 
and what i have to write in brackets when i using `<?= Yii::t()?>`
P.S. i am also changed language in my config.
P.P.S. i generated models and cruds for this tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            '*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\DbMessageSource',
                'forceTranslation'=>true,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

set parameter `forceTranslation` as `true`. This trick helps me.

Comment: /**
     * @var bool whether to force message translation when the source and target languages are the same.
     * Defaults to false, meaning translation is only performed when source and target languages are different.
     */
    public $forceTranslation = false;